# Group Policy object not updating

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, group-policy

I have a Folder Redirection policy and I changed the path on our 2003 domain. However even after gpupdate /force the client (Win 7)  still tries to access the old path and give me the "Windows cannot access ..." and the old share. Nothing has changed and the group policy is being applied , it simply isn't updating?

Comment: Have you checked the folder redirection operational event log on the W7 client for any clues? applications and services/microsoft/Windows/folder redirection/operational is the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `gpresult /v`. That'll give you a great starting place to start looking into if the policy is being applied correctly or not.

Comment: Thanks, with that and rsop.msc I was able to determine its somehow a glitch that requires the local profile be remade to take effect.